# Gradle build fails if trying to implement interface

Tags: java, gradle

I have my gradle project building fine unless I try to implement specific interface: It imports some unresolved package. However, if the interface is used do describe types (method arguments. etc.), everything compiles fine.

How should I fix the build to be able to implement that interface?

Comment: We're gonna need some details and code here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extend a class or implement an interface, you also need their dependencies in the compile classpath. If you just use the class or interface in fields, parameters, annotations and so on, you only need the class or interface itself in the compile classpath.

This is not Gradle specific but also true for plain commandline Java compiler.

Comment: any idea how can I find all the dependencies? In gradle dependencies it's a leaf node :(

Comment: If you have proper packages, the dependencies should be pulled in transitively automatically. It seems the Metadata of that package is not correctly declared if you didn't manually set transitivity to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not related to gradle, it is related to basic software engineering. If you want to use an interface, you need to implement it, because it does not include any implementation logic and it is nothing more than just a frame of what you need to implement. You can read more about interfaces in official documentations.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html